# Converting GUID to String

Tags: .net, guid, tostring

why doesn't this work?

MsgBox("F6D8C47B-46E6-4E93-A393-00085ACA2242").ToString.Replace("-", "")

Comment: What's an MsgBox?  What does it's ToString() method supposed to do?  What are you getting instead of your intended results?

Comment: There shouldn't be punishment for being a confused newbie. +1

Comment: I'm assuming that in your real code "F6D8C47B-46E6-4E93-A393-00085ACA2242" is actually a variable and not a literal string?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're calling ToString on the MsgBox, not the Guid, which apparently is already a string. Try

```
MsgBox("F6D8C47B-46E6-4E93-A393-00085ACA2242".Replace("-",""))
```

Comment: or MsgBox(new Guid("F6D8C47B-46E6-4E93-A393-00085ACA2242").ToString().Replace("-", ""))

Comment: Why convert it to a Guid only to convert it back to a string?

Comment: I think the literal string was just for explanitory purposes, it is probably a string variable in the real code.

Comment: Ah, maybe I'm misunderstanding something, apologies if I am, but even if it is a string variable, why make it a Guid in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

```
MsgBox(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N").ToUpper());
```

Comment: Not a good answer, just copy n pasta code in here with no explanations for other readers...